# Is there a way to get a reference to a mutable sub-slice of a Vec<T>?

Tags: rust, slice

I want to preallocate a vector and then write into slices of it, including [writing to it from a `TcpStream`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/net/struct.TcpStream.html#impl-Read) , which takes a `buf: &mut [u8]` as an argument.

```
// Create a vec with 256MB capacity
let mut myvec: Vec<u8> = Vec::with_capacity(268435456);

// Grow the vec to 256MB and initialize it with zeroes 
myvec.resize(268435456, 0x00);

// Try to get a mutable slice of the first 1kb of the vec
let body_slice: &mut [u8] = myvec[10..1034];
```

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/lib.rs:9:33
  |
9 |     let body_slice: &mut [u8] = myvec[10..1034];
  |                     ---------   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |                     |           |
  |                     |           expected `&mut [u8]`, found slice `[u8]`
  |                     |           help: consider mutably borrowing here: `&mut myvec[10..1034]`
  |                     expected due to this
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want this:

```
let body_slice: &mut [u8] = &mut myvec[10..1034];
```

Comment: perfect, tyvm. should have been obvious, but that [] syntax cofused me and I don't see a good reference for it.

Comment: For reference, here's the [SliceMut trait](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.SliceMut.html) or the non-sugar version [slice_mut](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/trait.SliceExt.html#tymethod.slice_mut).

Comment: I think this answer is soon going to be obsolete, with the advent of RFC #439 (https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0439-cmp-ops-reform.md). If I'm reading this correctly, once this is complete then `&mut myvec[10..1034]` should work as expected.

Comment: As of the latest nightlies, neither the accepted answer, nor the rfc439 approaches appear to work. Only way I can get it to work now is with &mut* myvec{10..1034]

Comment: I can't get it to work using any of the three ways mentioned so far, LOL

Comment: @Trejkaz the way suggested in the answer seems to work: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e1dfaaa9829a74e5cc62b5d1115d661c